# Is data sent to file streams (i/o streams) buffered in main memory & then sent to disk?

Tags: file, stream, hardware

Just out of curiosity, what exactly are file streams at the hardware level.  I just read about how these abstract streams were a solution to keep i/o devices independent from programs & programmers in the legacy days.. so can someone explain the data flow, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are is any file hardware left. All modern storage provides block storage. Anything else is a software interpretation., including file streams.

Comment: So when a high level language declares a file stream for output or input, before the data reaches disk, is there any buffering done in main memory?